# My passport name changed for the same country without visa

Tags: passports, biometric-passports, ecuador

i have read two questions with same case 
the first was this [I am British, If I change my passport name, would other countries know my old name?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44300/i-am-british-if-i-change-my-passport-name-would-other-countries-know-my-old-na)
the second was this [Does a new passport number mean new records?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116345/does-a-new-passport-number-mean-new-records)
but i don't get my answer let me explain.
I am Egyptian and i have visited Ecuador visa free for Egyptians for 90 days and  i have stay for 90 days i had passport with name NOIEMANY MOUSTAFA MOHAMED MOUSTAFA and lost it when I got another one with new number and full name NOMANY MOSTAFA MOHAMED MOSTAFA
my questions is :
1- how do immigration authorities track my previous trips ?
2- for immigration authorities i am the same person or another one ?
Note: the Egyptian passport non-biometric and Ecuador no have any airport biometrics (eyes or fingerprint)

Comment: Are you trying to evade immigration scrutiny because you’re up against overstay rules? Or are you trying to make sure they know who you are because you have a prior visa?

Comment: No, I need to know this because I have documents in this country (bank account and marriage certificate) with the old name and I don't have the old passport

Comment: I trying to make sure they know who you are because you have a prior visa

Answer (score 6):

Immigration rules are about you as a person. Changing your name does not make you a different person.

Different countries might be good or bad at identifying people who change their names and travel on new passports as being people who have visited before. However, we don't give advice about how to break the law or how likely you are to get caught if you do break the law. My guess is that, anyway, most countries aren't going to be fooled when all the passport details match except that the number has changed (people renew their passports all the time) and that there's been a small change of spelling.

Comment: No, I need to know this because I have documents in this country (bank account and marriage certificate) with the old name and I don't have the old passport

Comment: You didn’t mention anything like that in your question so how was I supposed to know? And how are they related to travel or the immigration authorities?

Comment: If your question is about banking and other services to residents, you will be better asking at [expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/)